# Add data to Shadow Dom elements automatically

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I need to add password and username automatically and then click "Enter" to Shadow DOM elements:

```
<input type="text" class="_y" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="username" value="">
#shadow-root (user-agent)
<div id="inner-editor"></div>
<div pseudo="-webkit-input-placeholder" id="placeholder" style="visibility: visible; text-overflow: clip;">Username</div>
</input>
</div>
```

The second field is the same.

I have the code for adding:

```
document.querySelector('input').value = "username";
document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].value ="password";
```

It's works, I see my username and password in the necessary fields. But when I click the button using the next code:

```
document.querySelector('button').click()
```

I see the process starts and then nothing and the fields become empty.

The button code:

```
 <span class="_r ">
<button class="_a">Enter</button>
</span>
```

If I do this manually, everything works without problems. Why does not automatic mode work?

Comment: what type of error you are getting in console?

Comment: @Supersharp I added the button code

Comment: @santoshgore Incorrect username or password (this error in the browser window), but when I click button automatically the fields become empty that is why I catch this error. The console has no errors.

Comment: All these elements are in the same form <form class="_k">elements</form>

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I's because when you click on the `<button>` your form is sent.

If you didn't specify where to send the form, the current page is requested again, and the content of the `<input>` tags is reset.

You should set the `onsubmit` attribute like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

...or call a JavaScript function that will process the form (and return `false` if you don't want to navigate to a page).

```
<form onsubmit="process()">
```

Or specify the URL where to send the form in the `action` attribute:

```
<form action="/form">
```

Comment: I want to log in automatically using javascript. I can not change the page code.How do I change "onsubmit" if I can't change the page code?

Comment: I did  document.querySelector('form').setAttribute("onSubmit", "false") before click, but have the same result, only without "Incorrect username or password" error.

Comment: You can try it yourself: google.com (add Query and click "Search") using javascript, instagram.com(add pas and name and click "Log in"), facebook etc. have a similar logic(shadow dom), such as I described above.

Comment: It works. The problem is that you don't provide the right username/password – Don't block the submission if you want to connect to a server! Read my answer.

Comment: It's strange. What i do?: document.querySelector('input').value = "username"; document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].value = "pass"; document.querySelector('form').setAttribute("onsubmit", "return false;"); document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click()

Comment: don't block the submission with "return false" if you want to submit the form... don't click on any button at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand what shall i do? Ok, I add username and pass. What should I do next?

Comment: This is what I did in the beginning, as I wrote above. This does not work, the page reloads with empty fields and produces an error, that is why I asked this question.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a complete, reproductible example (4th edition)

Comment: No proplem! My steps: 1) I open instagram.com in Chrome browser, 2) In the same window I open Google developer tools console, 3) I write in console  - document.querySelector('input').value = "username"(my username added), 4) document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].value ="password" (my password added) 5) The last one, i add - document.querySelector('button').click(). After that I see the page restarts with empty fields. When I do the same manually I log in without any problem.